# adding ManyToOne mapping with existing column

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc

I came across a situation where I have to establish a many to one relationship between two tables with precondition as below:

table A:

-----primary_key_a------------column_a--------column_x---------

example:

------1----------------------------2050--------ABC

------2----------------------------2050--------AAA

------3----------------------------9090--------ABC

------4----------------------------9090--------AAA

table B:

-----primary_key_B------------column_B--------column_C---------

example:

------2050----------------------------SSS--------KKK

------2090----------------------------YYY--------KKK

As shown in two tables, primary_key_B and column_a have same values but in existing table, they have different column names (primary_key_B for table B and column_a for table A). In existing records, there are cases where some value of primary_key_B may not be in column_a and vice versa but we want to populate that going further

My Existing POJO for table_a and table_b are as below:

```
    @Entity
    public class PojoForA
    {

        @Id
        @Column(name = "primary_key_a")
        private Integer id;

        @Column(name = "column_a")
        private String b;
        @Column(name = "column_x")
        private String c;
       //getter/setters
}

@Entity
public class PojoForB
{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "primary_key_B")
    private Integer idB;

    @Column(name = "column_b")
    private String b;
    @Column(name = "column_c")
    private String c;
   //getter/setters
```

}

Then I added below changes in Pojo A for Many to one Mapping:

```
@Entity
public class PojoForA
{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "primary_key_a")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "column_a")
    private String b;
    @Column(name = "column_x")
    private String c;

 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "idB",nullable=false,referencedColumnName = "primary_key_B")
   //getter/setters
```

}

It did not establish the relationship that I wanted to build. Table A already has the column with different name with same data as primary key of Table B.
When I tried to run, I get below error:

```
    Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "tablea0_.primary_key_B" not found; SQL statement:.........
org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:357)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
        at org.h2.expression.ExpressionColumn.optimize(ExpressionColumn.java:150)
```

how do I solve this problem? Basically, I do not want to change the table structure but have a many to one relationship between table_a and table_b

Comment: The `ManyToOne` belongs in table B since it holds the foreign key to table A. there will be many table B entries for one given table A entry.

Comment: not correct. ManyToOne should be in table A and for many table A records, there should be one record in table B. If you see the example

Answer (score 0):

You have put the ManoToOne reference in the Table B. First try to map your entities ok. I can see in your log file that there is a column not recognized, the reference column named primary_key_b must have a foreign key to table A.

The way to reference is in the mapping is:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "primary_key_b", referencedColumnName = "column_a")
@ManyToOne(optional = true) // This is because you can have null values I understood.
```